# Insert text with Apostrophe to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I just started helping on a site where there is an admin section that allows the site owner to input text to display on the site.  They have a problem when adding text with apostrophes because it breaks the PHP statement.  I have looked at using mysql_real_escape_string command, but not sure the best way to use it.  The original code is below.  Any suggestions would be great!

```
<textarea name="descr" cols="76" rows="5" id="descr" tabindex="5" onBlur="this.value=removeMSWordChars(this.value);">
  <?php echo $data['descr']; ?>

  </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'descr' );
    </script>
   </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Prepared Statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html), they allow you to:

- Make you code safe against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks
- Insert any character easily into the database, without caring about escaping.

You seem to be still using the MySQL-extension (the one with [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)): Note that this extension is deprecated and does not support Prepared Statements. You should switch to either [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), the link at the top explains how to.

Comment: The comic doesn't really add anything to your answer, especially when dealing with a novice.

Comment: @Marty You might be right, removed it. I thought it could help understand the dangers.

Comment: I'd retract that downvote if it were mine, unfortunately it's not.